# Deallocating Object3D

Tags: javascript, memory-management, three.js

I load a model from an obj file using in addition the mtl file. How do I properly dispose off or deallocate all the geometry/materials/textures from the returned Object3D in r55?

Comment: just as a reference for people landing here. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/33199591/1980846

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
object.traverse( function ( child ) {

    if ( child.geometry !== undefined ) {

        child.geometry.dispose();
        child.material.dispose();

    }

} );
```

Comment: Well if I add these lines after line 81 in webgl_loader_obj_mtl.html nothing happens. I actually would have expected to see no geometry since once it is loaded, I dispose of it.

Comment: I also verified in Firebug that the code inside the if statement does get executed. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [mrdoob's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14652105/1763602), I created a function that recursively dispose a three.js object. I added it to my personal three.js util library: https://github.com/MarcoSulla/my3

```
function dispose3(obj) {
    /**
     *  @author Marco Sulla (marcosullaroma@gmail.com)
     *  @date Mar 12, 2016
     */

    "use strict";

    var children = obj.children;
    var child;

    if (children) {
        for (var i=0; i<children.length; i+=1) {
            child = children[i];

            dispose3(child);
        }
    }

    var geometry = obj.geometry;
    var material = obj.material;

    if (geometry) {
        geometry.dispose();
    }

    if (material) {
        var texture = material.map;

        if (texture) {
            texture.dispose();
        }

        material.dispose();
    }
},
```

My hope is this function will be added in three.js code, in `Scene.remove` method (maybe called only if you set an optional flag).

Comment: This is what I was doing by myself, but unfortunately that does not dispose every texture.

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
function removeReferences(removeme){
  try{
    removeme.traverse(function(ob){
      try{
        renderer.deallocateObject(ob);
      }catch(e){} 
      try{
        ob.geometry.deallocate();
      }catch(e){}
      try{
        ob.material.deallocate();
      }catch(e){} 
      try{
        ob.deallocate()
      }catch(e){}
    });
  }catch(e){}
}
```

Comment: On r55 renderer.deallocateObject seems not to exist.

Comment: I got this from one of the examples. It must have used an older version of three.js